# Is there any risk of a race condition when runing ps?

Tags: ps, background-process

I'm starting a long-running process (in Java, on the off-chance that's relevant) and would like to then capture its PID via `ps`.  I'm essentially doing this:

```
Process longRunningProcess = new ProcessBuilder(...).start();

Process psProcess = new ProcessBuilder("ps").start();
psProcess.waitFor();
// extract the PID from the output of psProcess
```

Or effectively equivalently in Bash:

```
$ long_running_process > /dev/null & ps
```

The question is, is it possible for the long-running process to be in some still-starting-up state that `ps` will not yet report?  Or is there any sort of guarantee that by the time `ps` is executed the long-running process will be started-up enough to be visible?  Running the command repeatedly *appears* to always include the process, but that's obviously not proof of anything.

[This article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#But_I.27m_on_some_old_legacy_Unix_system_that_doesn.27t_have_pgrep.21__What_do_I_do.3F) warns that there may be a race-condition on commands started *after* `ps` is started (e.g. `ps | grep`) but doesn't mention anything about processes started before `ps`.

Comment: Maybe this can help you by doing it differently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750470/how-to-get-pid-of-process-ive-just-started-within-java-program ?

Comment: @lserni thanks for the reference, I've looked at several options, and for my use case getting the PID from `ps` will be cleanest - assuming it can be trusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the operations are comparable to OpenJDK [v6-b14](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/ProcessImpl.java#ProcessImpl.start%28java.lang.String[]%2Cjava.util.Map%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cboolean%29), the PID *will* be available to `ps` when scanning the `/proc` virtual file system. You cannot be sure that the process has really started (i.e. done anything); all you know is that a PID has been reserved and scheduled (come to think of it, the process might have *died* and be in a zombie state).

However, since `ps` locks you to Unix systems, you could use Reflection to dig into the object returned by ProcessBuilder on the understanding that it will lead you to a UnixProcess:

```
final class  [More ...] UNIXProcess extends Process {
    private FileDescriptor stdin_fd;
    private FileDescriptor stdout_fd;
    private FileDescriptor stderr_fd;
    private int pid; <----------------------------------------------
    private int exitcode;
```

Of course this **is** a hack, but not too different from spawning `ps` - and surely faster. And not really all that risky - I don't see a pid field called `pid` changing very soon.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not intimately familiar with Java, but by the time `ProcessBuilder.start` returns, it must have started something. It can have set up a callback inside the existing thread to be executed later to create the child process, or it can have started another thread in the same process that eventually creates the child process, or it can have called `fork` to create a child process. I doubt that it's any of the first two since it would be harder to get right; any reference to the subprocess, including mechanisms to communicate with it or to retrieve its status, would have to wait until the process is created.

Thus by the time `ProcessBuilder.start` returns, you can be sure that the process has been created. However, this doesn't mean that there's no race condition. If the process exits or crashes soon after having been started, it might already be dead by the time you look at it. The process ID will still exist until its parent calls one of the [`wait` family of system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait_(system_call)); if the process has died, the PID remains valid as long as the process is a [zombie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process), i.e. as long as the parent hasn't called `wait`.

So the only way to be sure that the process ID is valid is to coordinate with the parent and ensure that the parent has already called `fork` and hasn't called `wait` yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem in the past.  I solved it by doing:

```
exec java WhateverTheClassNameIs -p $$
```

where "-p" is a flag that indicates "my PID is the value of this flag". You have to code that part in your Java `main()` method.

That has to be the last line of the shell script, as the `exec` primitive loads `java` over the shell itself. The exit status of your program will be the exit status of `WhateverTheClassNameIs`, not the shell's exit status, as it really no longer exists. This can lead to somewhat contorted code, but I couldn't find a better way of getting the PID into a Java program.

Comment: I'm not asking about the PID of the running Java process.  I'm asking about a process started by Java - though the question itself is about Unix behavior, in theory it's not relevant that it's started by Java.